# Wohin stellt man das Wort "schon" in Perfekt-Sätzen?

Tags: sentence-structure, adverb, perfect-tense

Beispiele:

- Ich habe Alex eine Tasse Kaffee **schon** gebracht.
- Ich habe sie **schon** Alex gebracht.
- Ich habe ihm **schon** eine Tasse Kaffee gebracht.
- Ich habe sie ihm **schon** gebracht.

Warum gehet "schon" in den verschiedenen Stellen? Hat das Wort keine feste stelle in den Sätzen, z.B. vor dem Verb in Partizip II (gebracht)?

Ist es ein größer Fehler, "schon" in der anderen Stelle zu stellen? Z.B., im zweiten Satz:

- Ich habe sie Alex **schon** gebracht.

Comment: Der erste Satz fühlt sich falsch für mich an.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Das Wort "schon" steht im Satz direkt vor dem worauf es sich bezieht und kann in deinem Beispielsatz deswegen an mehreren Stellen stehen, ohne dass es falsch ist. Dafür bekommen die Sätze aber leicht unterschiedliche Bedeutungen.

- „Ich habe Alex eine Tasse Kaffee **schon** gebracht.“ kann eine passende Antwort darauf sein, dass dich jemand bittet Alex eine Tasse Kaffee zu bringen, aber das ist eine Aufgabe, die du schon erledigt hast. „Schon“ bezieht sich hier auf die Aktion (gebracht), die gemacht worden ist.
- „Ich habe Alex **schon** eine Tasse Kaffee gebracht.“ verschiebt den Bezug von „schon“ von der Aktion auf die Tasse Kaffee. Wenn jemand dich bittet z.B. Alex nicht nur eine Tasse Kaffee, sondern auch ein Stück Kuchen zu bringen und du hast Alex schon die Kaffeetasse gebracht, aber den Kuchen noch nicht, kann das eine passende Antwort sein.
- „Ich habe **schon** Alex eine Tasse Kaffee gebracht.“ betont, dass sich „schon“ auf Alex bezieht und passt, wenn du z.B. nicht nur Alex, sondern auch Maria eine Tasse Kaffe bringen sollst, du hast schon Alex den Kaffee gebracht, aber Maria hat noch nichts bekommen.

Allerdings ist die Wortstellung in diesem Beispiel ziemlich locker und alle drei Varianten könnten auch für den Anwendungsfall im ersten Punkt hinhalten.

Comment: Die zweite Variante ist gleichzeitig die "neutralste". Das heißt, abseits von dem speziellen Kontext, den du ganz richtig beschreibst (und der im Gesprochenen vermutlich durch eine Betonung zusätzlich hervorgehoben wird), würde man in dieser Stellung das "schon" auf den ganzen Satz beziehen.

Comment: Im dritten Beispiel kann sich alternativ "schon" auch auf den gesamten Rest des Satzes beziehen: "Meine Aufgaben bestehen darin, Alex eine Tasse Kaffee zu bringen, Maria ein Stück Kuchen zu servieren und das neue Zahnbürstenmodell von Ronaldine abzuholen. Ich habe schon Alex eine Tasse Kaffee gebracht. Es sind nun also noch zwei weitere Aufgaben zu erledigen."

Comment: Letztendlich ist auch "Schon habe ich Alex eine Tasse Kaffee gebracht." eine grammatikalisch korrekte Wortstellung. In dieser Wortstellung wird mit dem "schon" allerdings eher ausgedrückt, dass die gesamte Handlung besonders schnell abgeschlossen wurde.

Comment: Hängt die Position des Wortes "schon" davon ab, ob ich Pronomen oder Nomen verwende? Z.B., ich verwende Ihre zweite Variante (wenn ich nur eine Tasse Kaffee gebracht habe, aber ein Stück Kuchen noch nicht), aber tausche "eine Tasse Kaffee" gegen "sie" (Nomen gegen Pronomen). Behält "schon" seine Stelle vor "sie"? Dann, soweit ich weiß, geht Pronomen vor Nomen. Also, ist es richtig, wenn ich die Bedeutung des Satzes behalten wollte: "Ich habe **schon sie** Alex gebracht."?

Comment: Beim ersten Beispiel stört mich das _eine_, es sollte besser heißen: _Ich habe Alex den / seinen Kaffee schon gebracht,_ oder: ... _habe Alex schon Kaffee gebracht._ Ähnlich beim zweiten Beispiel, auch da würde ich eher sagen _ich hab ihm schon (den) Kaffee gebracht_ (den Rest muss er noch bekommen). Im dritten Fall würde ich sagen: _Bis jetzt hat erst Alex seinen Kaffee (bekommen)._ Die Sätze sind nicht direkt falsch, aber mehr oder weniger schräg. So, wie sie da stehen, würde ich sie eher folgendermaßen fortsetzen: ...

Comment: ... 1 _Ich habe Alex **eine** Tasse Kaffee schon (mal) gebracht, aber er wollte ja **drei**._  2 _Ich habe Alex schon (mal) eine Tasse **Kaffee** gebracht, jetzt fehlt aber noch der Kuchen._  3 _Ich habe schon (mal) dem **Alex** seine Tasse Kaffee gebracht, die anderen warten noch auf **ihre**._ Die Sätze funktionieren nur mit speziellen Betonungen oder kleinen Veränderungen halbwegs vernünftig; das lässt sich aber schriftlich nur teilweise wiedergeben.